# Changing bluetooth class to act as a hands free device and car audio

Tags: pi-2, audio, raspbian-stretch, bluetooth

Good morning folks,

I have been using this tool to quickly configure my Pi2 as a bluetooth audio link to my camper van, it works brilliantly.

My question is regarding changing the class of the bluetooth device so it can receive phone call audio too like a normal car hands free kit.

I will admit I am not 100% familiar with all the terminology involved so will apologise in advance.

If I change the class value in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf and reboot I get a different class listed in the bluetoothctl tool output. To get the class I used this tool https://www.ampedrftech.com/cod.htm

When I make the change I think the system is correcting the Class to be Rendering (Speaker) and Capturing (Microphone) Device but I do not see the phone audio option on my phone (See screenshot).

/etc/bluetooth/main.conf

```
[General]

# Default adapter name
# Defaults to 'BlueZ X.YZ'
#Name = BlueZ

# Default device class. Only the major and minor device class bits are
Name = Orion Audio Link
# considered. Defaults to '0x000000'.
#Class = 0x000100
Class = 0x600420
```

This is the output from bluetoothctl

```
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/bluetooth $ sudo bluetoothctl
[NEW] Controller 00:1A:7D:DA:71:13 Orion Audio Link [default]
[NEW] Device 54:B1:21:94:3C:26 deans
[bluetooth]# show
Controller 00:1A:7D:DA:71:13
    Name: Orion Audio Link
    Alias: Orion Audio Link
    Class: 0x0c0420
    Powered: yes
    Discoverable: yes
    Pairable: yes
    UUID: Headset AG                (00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Source              (0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d052B
    Discovering: no
```

[image: Bluetooth pairing profiles]

Comment: I'm trying to build the same thing. Can you share your codes, resources? And did you fix the problem? Thank you

Comment: @ÜmitDuran I solved it by using a script to configure it, there are a couple out there.  This is one of them that works great https://github.com/bareinhard/super-simple-raspberry-pi-audio-receiver-install

Comment: @ÜmitDuran I think this one is a little simpler https://github.com/nicokaiser/rpi-audio-receiver

Answer (score 0):

I know im 4 years to late but i think i found something because i have a similar trouble

So theres a generator to generate a Class of Device http://bluetooth-pentest.narod.ru/software/bluetooth_class_of_device-service_generator.html

and there is also a post wich can also help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70535290/bluetoothclass-of-devices-what-is-what

Comment: this does not bring any new information